# Storing chat messages for a messaging microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, message

I am making a real-time based chat microservice and this is my first time making such application.
I am kind of confused on how to store the conversations because I think storing them in a database (Cassandra or whatever) is not an optimal solution for the long run.

I've read about Apache Kafka and found that this could be a solution to my problem. Thus, I'm not quite sure if I'm there yet.
I just need to know If Kafka is enough without the need of an external database (Just talking about the data related to the messages though, not the users or any other type of data I may need). Because I've read that Kafka provides in its topics the option to use a retention time of "-1" which basically means forever, but AS LONG AS THE SERVER IS RUNNING while I'm not sure I can keep the same server running forever, could someone please clarify this for me ?

Comment: Facebook, for example, has a history of using a combination of MySQL / HBase / Cassandra for messaging platform... What makes you think you shouldn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> read about Apache Kafka and found that this could be a solution to my problem.... need to know If Kafka is enough

For storage, sure. For message delivery to clients, no.

Some extreme examples come up immediately when considering using any message broker

- you have one topic per "chat conversation", and your chat app becomes really popular - you now have hundreds of thousands of topics, which Kafka cannot handle. A database can be filtered/sharded/partitioned by many fields, including user id
- chat messages must be ordered, therefore you could really one use one partition for all topics ; with a database, you can always order by timestamp at query time
- If you used a "firehose" approach of one topic with all messages from everybody, then redistribute the data downstream, then infrequent clients are going to lag behind the most frequent user-client because there are more messages to process.

Most importantly, chat apps are frontend applications; Kafka is a backend technology and doesn't "push" to frontend services. For mobile/browser use-cases, you wouldn't have access to embed a Kafka consumer in them. A REST API layer would have to be added to request messages, just as it would with a database.

A better design would be to generate message events rather than store message data - E.g. "At time `T`, user `X` send `'M'` message with content `C` to location/users `L`"... A topic with that data does not need to be persisted forever, just long enough to be consumed. And still, with all that information, you then need to consider topic partitioning for scalability, then you can filter and dump that into some more persistent location because your user-facing application wouldn't be consuming every single one of those events.

> I'm not sure I can keep the same server running forever

Someone will have to. Use a hosted solution, if *you* cannot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, your help is really appreciated.
Thus, can you please explain more what do you mean by "Someone will have to. Use a hosted solution, if you cannot." ? I don't understand this last part, as if I use a database will I still need to keep the kafka cluster running forever ?
Another part I didn't get is "your user-facing application wouldn't be consuming every single one of those events.", Idk what you mean exactly, are you saying that I shouldn't save the whole conversation but the "latest" part of it instead ?
Thanks again

Comment: 1) A hosted solution - Aiven, Confluent Cloud, Amazon MSK, etc. 2) A database would still need running, and ideally would be written to out of a Kafka topic, so you'd need to keep both running 3) I'm saying of a topic of all user interactions, you need to divide all chat events between more specific chats, in addition to make them available to a front end client rather than directly forwarding somehow from Kafka via a standard consumer (since a consumer must read sequentially, and cannot skip over records it's not interested in)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure I can keep the same server running forever

In practice, you have more than one server. The Kafka server process (known as a broker) is designed to run as a cluster. Data is written to one and replicated to others. If one server becomes unavailable the data is then served from another.

> I think storing them in a database (Cassandra or whatever) is not an optimal solution for the long run.

I'm not sure that's a correct assumption on which to base your usage of Kafka. Both RDBMS and NoSQL stores can—and are—used as long term stores of data for numerous applications including chat.
It depends on your use case, the volumes you envisage, and perhaps also how else you're going to use the data.